# Transfer Ubuntu server into vm

Tags: virtualization, transfer

I have an Ubuntu 22 server on a machine and I want to "transfer" it into another machine - more specifically into a machine which runs ESXI platform. I want to set up a virtual machine on ESXI, install Ubuntu on it and use it as my server, from now on.
The first approach would be setting up all things manually - install Ubuntu on virtual machine, install and configure everything (users, samba, webserver, mysqlserver, ssl, packages - everything!) from scratch.. Of course, I would like to avoid that approach and I 'm looking for something easier and reliable.
I don't know if hardware differences between two machines (different disks, raid disks on vm etc) would be a limiting factor.
Can anyone give me an advice about this server-transfer? How can I do it? Is there any tool I could use?
Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 22?  So you're trying to *migrate* a Ubuntu Core 22 server?  (*22 & 22.04 are different Ubuntu products; 22 being a flavor of 22.04 Server*).

Comment: There are two tools that you can give a try Clonezilla and vCenter Converter

Comment: The approach you avoid is actually the one I would reach for first. You are balancing risks: Tedious configuration vs tedious troubleshooting. Tedious configuration has a likelihood of a successful result in a predictable time. Alternately, if you are feeling lucky and you have a good set of full-system backups, you might be able to simply restore onto the VM. It might work. It might not.

Comment: I agree with @user535733. Bite the bullet and set things up fresh, documenting the steps that you followed so that the next time is easier. The amount of money that I have earned from clients who tried to skip steps only to create much more work later is no joke, and blindly copying systems generally reinforces the "don't know, don't care" mentality that creates bigger problems in the future 